# how to format CSV for mongoimport date type

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoimport

I'm importing some CSV files, and using what should be a legal date format. But getting this error:

```
could not parse token '2018-01-01 03:00:00' to type date
```

my data looks like this:

```
17544,1,2018-01-01 00:00:00,1,1.0
17545,1,2018-01-01 01:00:00,1,1.0
17546,1,2018-01-01 02:00:00,1,1.0
17547,1,2018-01-01 03:00:00,1,2.0
```

my format looks like the examples from the docs
https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongoimport/

```
mongoimport --type csv -d databoard -c samples \
    --fields="row.int32(),stationID.int32(),ts.date(),speciesID.int32(),counts.int32()" \
    --columnsHaveTypes --drop data/raw/sample2.csv
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm also not sure how to use `--headerFields` with `--fields` so i removed the fields from the first row of the date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

according to docs, you have to provide an argument in date which specifies the date format

```
mongoimport --type csv -d databoard -c samples \
    --fields="row.int32(),stationID.int32(),ts.date(2006-01-02 15:04:05),speciesID.int32(),counts.int32()" \
    --columnsHaveTypes --drop data/raw/sample2.csv
```

Comment: To all these good people who've been wondering if they can change that ridiculous arbitrary mock date in the header, the answer is... *not really*. You can try, but most attempts will fail. I've succeeded in changing the seconds to :04, :05 or :06.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly have the first line of your CSV file to contain your date types. In which case you will want to use the `--headerline` option.

First line would be:
`row.int32(),stationID.int32(),ts.date(2006-01-02 15:04:05),speciesID.int32(),counts.int32()`

Also, remember that the __ridiculous arbitrary `2006-01-02 15:04:05` or so (more or less 1 second) date must be followed...